# jshint es6 const if else block errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jshint

With this code:

```
const db        = {};
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
db.sequelize = sequelize;
```

I've got the error

> 'sequelize' is not defined

is there a way to use const and avoid such as workaround ?

like

```
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
   sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
   sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refactor your code to use a function to create the actual objects, like this

```
function SequelizeFactory(config) {
  if (config.use_env_variable) {
    return new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
  } else {
    return new Sequelize(config.database,
                         config.username,
                         config.password,
                         config);
  }
}
```

and then just assign the result of calling the function to `sequelize`.

```
const sequelize = SequelizeFactory(config);
```